# Inserting commas dynamically to a list inside the view, angular js

Tags: angularjs, list, view, angularjs-ng-repeat, delimiter

I've got some html that looks like this

```
columns = [<span ng-repeat-start= "col in colsList">"{{col}}"</span><span ng-repeat-end></span>]
```

Which is giving me nearly the correct output, something like this.

```
columns = ["a" "b" "c" "d"]
```

Is there anything  within angular that will allow me to easily separate these items with commas? I tried doing this

```
columns = [<span ng-repeat-start= "col in colsList">"{{col}}, "</span><span ng-repeat-end></span>]
```

Which ended up giving me output such as this.

```
columns = ["a", "b", "c", "d",]
```

Which is so close to what I want, but I cannot have the extra comma after the "d".

So, is there anything in angular like this, that will allow me to represent a typical list inside the view, separated by a delimeter, in this case a comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[<span ng-repeat="col in colsList">"{{ col + ($last ? '"' : '", ') }}</span>]
```

Comment: It appears as though the end bracket of my list is being included as a part of the quotation (it is colored green, the color of strings in my editor), Is there a way to not include the final bracket as a part of the last string in the list? I've tried messing around with the variables next to "$last" without luck

Comment: Your editor is confused, but the code is correct. Try using `&quot;` instead of `"`, maybe that will make your editor happy.

Comment: I don't know why I said editor.. browser is what I meant. Same case though

Comment: Even in your example here, the final span tag is considered "quoted"

Comment: A browser doesn't color quotes in green. The code works fine here on Firefox, Safari and Chrome: http://plnkr.co/edit/lNCjNQzACsD45f4UkyBp?p=preview. What is the problem?

Comment: See how above, the final "span" tag is colored red? It is considered part of the quotation. I am using google pretty print in conjunction with a directive, this is what I meant by "editor"

Comment: above what? No, I can't see anything anywhere. The dom generated by the code is 4 spans, containing respectively `"a", `, `"b", `, `"c", ` and `"d"`. What else would you want?

Comment: Was referring to how quoted strings are in red, where as normal html text is in black. I am looking at the given answer.

Comment: That means that the pretty-printer used by StackOverflow is confused by the valid source code in my answer. But how is that important? Do you care about how the source code looks like in StancOverflow, or by how the output produced by AngularJS when interpreting that code looks like in a browser? The browser parses that correctly, and angularJS does as well, and transforms that to an opening bracket, followed by 4 spans, followed by a closing bracket.

Comment: The problem is that I'm using pretty print WITHIN my own code as well. Regardless, that is another issue, so I'll mark this as accepted.